# Setear valor a un estado que es un objeto en react

Tags: reactjs, objeto, usestate

Tengo un state que es el siguiente :

```
const [ totalStats, setTotalStats] = useState({
      tCombat: 0,
      tDurability: 0,
      tIntelligence: 0,
      tPower: 0,
      tSpeed: 0,
      tStrength: 0
    });
```

Necesito setear en cada posicion de este objeto lo que me devuelve cada reduce de estos:

```
const totalCombat = team.reduce((acum, heroe) => {
          return acum + Number(heroe.powerstats.combat);
        }, 0);
        console.log(totalCombat);
        console.log(totalStats);

        const totalDurability = team.reduce((acum, heroe) => {
          return acum + Number(heroe.powerstats.durability);
        }, 0);
        console.log(totalDurability);

        const totalIntelligence = team.reduce((acum, heroe) => {
          return acum + Number(heroe.powerstats.intelligence);
        }, 0);
        console.log(totalIntelligence);
```

Como puedo hacer en el setTotalStats para acceder a  cada posicion para volcar cada valor del return?

Por ejemplo volcar el resultado de TocalCombat en tCombat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la respuesta que te dieron **[acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492162/sumar-valores-traidos-de-una-api-react)**, deberías implementar tu **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** sólo una vez, y dentro de éste, armar la estructura que necesitas para *setear* tu `state`

Ahora bien, como deseas consultar varias veces el endpoint mediante el *ID* de cada personaje, podrías utilizar **[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)** para dicha operación. Una vez que la información de los héroes este en tu `state`, puedes - como ya te indique -, acumular las estadísticas mediante `reduce`.

```
const buildTotalStats = () => {
   const totalStats = teams.reduce((prev, curr) => ({
      totalCombat: prev.totalCombat + Number(curr.combat),
      totalDurability: prev.totalDurability + Number(curr.durability),
      totalIntelligence: prev.totalIntelligence + Number(curr.intelligence)
      // resto de propiedades...
   }), { totalCombat: 0, totalDurability: 0, totalIntelligence: 0 /* resto de propiedades */ });

   return totalStats;   
};
```

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/acumulacion-de-valores-mediante-reduce-bogxw)**, te dejo un ejemplo completo para que lo analices :)

Nos comentas si te sirvió, o si tienes dudas.

Comment: Hola Paulo ! el problema es que los powerstats los traigo de una api que llama a varios ids de heroes, cuando yo hago un reduce como el que vos me pones. powerstats.durability por ejemplo, no trae nada, por que no hace referencia a ningun heroe.

el mapeo si me sirvio pero para presentar cada dato individualmente no para sumar un total de powerstats.

Comment: @IgnacioHardoy editada!